# How to fix this SQL with UNION ALL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of daily data which I want to sum based on the Name, but group and display by date. I want to combine from Bookings table and POS. I manage to get each individual Bookings and POS but when tried to combine.. It failed

The select statement are all good but failed when I add in the UNION ALL statement

```
Select Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment,120), SUM(Amount) Amount 
From (
select PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) Date, SUM(Amount) Amount    
    From Payments P 
        Inner Join PaymentTypes PT On P.PaymentType = PT.ID 
        Inner Join BookingPayments BP On P.ID = BP.PaymentID 
        Inner Join Bookings B On B.ID = BP.BookingID 
        Where   DatePayment >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00' And 
                DatePayment <= '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997' And 
                BookingStatus IN (0,2,3,4,6) 
        Group By PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120)

UNION ALL
Select  PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) Date, SUM(P.Amount) Amount 
From Payments P 
        Inner Join PaymentTypes PT On P.PaymentType = PT.ID 
        Inner Join POSSales POS On P.ID = POS.PaymentID 
        Where   DatePayment >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00' And 
                DatePayment <= '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997' 
        Group By PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120))

a Group By Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120)
order by CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120);
```

I keep receiving the following error

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'DatePayment'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'DatePayment'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'DatePayment'.
```

Comment: **SOLVED** Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DatePayment you need to use Date as, you've used alias you need to select the alias name

```
   Select Name, CONVERT(char(10), `Date`,120), SUM(Amount) Amount 
        From (
        select PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) Date, SUM(Amount) Amount    
            From Payments P 
                Inner Join PaymentTypes PT On P.PaymentType = PT.ID 
                Inner Join BookingPayments BP On P.ID = BP.PaymentID 
                Inner Join Bookings B On B.ID = BP.BookingID 
                Where   DatePayment >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00' And 
                        DatePayment <= '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997' And 
                        BookingStatus IN (0,2,3,4,6) 
                Group By PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120)

        UNION ALL
        Select  PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) Date, SUM(P.Amount) Amount 
        From Payments P 
                Inner Join PaymentTypes PT On P.PaymentType = PT.ID 
                Inner Join POSSales POS On P.ID = POS.PaymentID 
                Where   DatePayment >= '2018-12-01 00:00:00' And 
                        DatePayment <= '2018-12-31 23:59:59.997' 
                Group By PT.Name, CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120)
)a Group By Name, CONVERT(char(10), `Date`, 120)
   order by CONVERT(char(10), `Date`, 120);
```

Comment: Don't make it a game of "spot the difference". Explain *what you've changed* (specifically) and *why*.

Comment: failed.. i got these error "Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'DatePayment'.
"

Comment: @fa06 failed too.. Error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '`'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
"

Comment: @Julie - if you want an answer that is *tested* and confirmed to work correctly, **help us to help you** by providing sample data, table structures and expected results in your question. (Ideally, the first two as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that we can copy & paste from your question to quickly recreate the sample)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yea.. sorry about that.. I thought.. its more about syntax which I'm unable to see.. it could be I just overlooked it.. It solved now.. thanks to fa06.. I'll update my code

Comment: @fa06 .. you are correct.. just for the 'Date'.. the value already converted.. so no need to convert again.. after remove the CONVERT(char(10), `Date`,120) into 'Date', it works.. Thanks a lot